# Filtering Django Queryset

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

If I have these models:

```
COLOR_OPTIONS = (
    ('BLA', 'Black'),
    ('WHI', 'White'),
    ('RED', 'Red'),
)

class Stuff(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Thing(models.Model):
    stuff = models.ForeignKey(Stuff)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COLOR_OPTIONS)
```

How do I use `.filter()` to filter different `Things` based on the different types of stuff, or the different colors?

---

How can I write my view so that I can filter for all of the various color options, and all of the different stuff options? This is kind of what I mean, but I dont know how to write the function correctly..

```
def filter(request):
    filter_color = Thing.objects.filter(color=COLOR_OPTIONS)
    filter_stuff = Thing.objects.filter(stuff=???)
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_things_based_on_stuff = Thing.objects.filter(stuff__text="some text here")

my_things_based_on_colors = Thing.objects.filter(color='BLA')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want it to be dynamic so that I can write one view to filter for all the different color options or the different stuff options. Any ideas to help me?

Comment: Are you looking for `Thing.objects.filter(color=COLOR_OPTIONS, stuff__text="some text here")`?

Comment: @NickB just replace the 'BLA' and "some text here" with your variables

Comment: Sorry to be a newb, but can you give me an example on how to set the variables given those model fields? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Come on, this all documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects

Comment: @NickB follow Django tutorial, if you encounter any problems, come back to here and we'll be glad to help you out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/